# Matching digits of a long integer to a list of numbers in Python 3

Tags: python, list, integer, compare

Learning Python 3 self guided. In C, I solved this problem using arrays of integers and comparing the array index to hard coded numbers. I'm having some difficulty porting this to Python 3.

Problem: Given a long integer, match the first two digits to a another set of digits.

```
number = 123456789
set1 = [21, 22, 23]
set2 = [11, 12, 19]

Intended Output
>>> Number is of type set2.
or
>>> Number is not in set1 or set2.
```

What I have been attempting to do is separate the first two digits (12) from number, and then do a comparison to each value in set1, and then set2. I starting doing this by converting number to a string and trying to use the cmp() function.

Since I am using python 3, cmp() is not a built in function, and this is where I got stuck. I started looking at different ways of implementing cmp(), and then started down a rabbit role reading documentation and posts. Finally decided just to ask my specific question.

My non-working, not-completed implementation is below. Still need to implement the proper number comparison through each element in each list. I feel like converting to a string isn't necessary, but I'm not sure exactly how else to do it.

```
number = 123456789
set1 = [21, 22, 23]
set2 = [11, 12, 19]
numberString = str(number)
numberType = "".join([numberString[0] + numberString[1])

if(cmp(numberType, set1) == 0):
    return 1
elif(cmp(numberType, set2) == 0):
    return 2
else:
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just easier to slice strings in Python.  So you can convert to str, take the first two digits, then convert back to int.  Then you can simply us `in` to check if it's in a list you have.

If you need it as a function, just define it, pass in the variable, and return the print string instead of printing.

```
number = 123456789
set1 = [21, 22, 23]
set2 = [11, 12, 19]
x = int(str(number)[:2])
if x in set1:
    print('Number is of type set1.')
elif x in set2:
    print('Number is of type set2.')
else:
    print('Number is not in set1 or set2')
...
Number is of type set2.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You made several new topics "click" for me here.

Comment: @JimDiroffII Coming from C you'll probably see yourself writing overly complex code when some built in functions already do what you want.  In time you'll definitely come to appreciate the simplistic nature of the language!